# remove _ as prefix from the multiple files in a directory in Soalris

Tags: shell

I have to remove `_` which is as prefix for a file. I used:

```
for i in _*.txt; do mv ${i} ${i/#_/''}; done
```

but it does not change the names of the files which has space in between as `_abc xyz-abc.txt`

I want `_` as prefix to be removed from all the files in a directory irrespective of space.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for i in ./_*.txt; do
  mv "$i" "${i#_}"
done
```

It assumed that you ran a POSIX shell - `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` with Solaris 10 and earlier.